# how i can upload more then 3 GB file to azure datalake in .net core api?

Tags: azure, file-upload, azure-blob-storage, streaming, azure-data-lake-gen2

My application has React UI .net core 6 microservice and then that microservice get stream data from UI and we tried to upload to DataLake but its taking longer time or it fails.

I already tried chunk upload with fetch and put calls  but its also not working with file
can we use azcopy with stream or any other option like  Azure data movement which can work with stream data and upload in parallel way so it guarantee and improve the speed of uploading this big file from UI.

```
 public async Task<bool> UploadFile(Guid id, Stream file, string name, string contentType)
{
    bool ret = true;
    int chunckSize = 2097152; //2MB
    int totalChunks = (int)(file.Length / chunckSize);
    if (file.Length % chunckSize != 0)
    {
        totalChunks++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < totalChunks; i++)
    {
        long position = (i * (long)chunckSize);
        int toRead = (int)Math.Min(file.Length - position + 1, chunckSize);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[toRead];
        await file.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, toRead);

        MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        content.Add(new StringContent(id.ToString()), "id");
        var meta = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new ChunkMetaData
        {
            UploadUid = id.ToString(),
            FileName = name,
            ChunkIndex = i,
            TotalChunks = totalChunks,
            TotalFileSize = file.Length,
            ContentType = contentType
        });
        content.Add(new StringContent(meta), "metaData");
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(buffer))
        {
            content.Add(new StreamContent(ms),"files");
            var response = await Client.PostAsync("/api/Upload", content).ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                ret = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

}

Comment: Could you share some of the code you tried?

Comment: code added in question self

Answer (score 0):

There is a UploadAsync method for uploading large files:

```
public async Task UploadFileBulk(DataLakeFileSystemClient fileSystemClient)
{
    DataLakeDirectoryClient directoryClient =
        fileSystemClient.GetDirectoryClient("my-directory");

    DataLakeFileClient fileClient = directoryClient.GetFileClient("uploaded-file.txt");

    FileStream fileStream =
        File.OpenRead("C:\\Users\\contoso\\file-to-upload.txt");

    await fileClient.UploadAsync(fileStream);

}
```

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-dotnet

Comment: this also not working for 3 gb file

Comment: What is the speed of your internet connection?

Comment: Could you test the above code with a 1 MB file first, to see how long it takes?

Comment: Sure will update apart of this
I m also trying  ParallelTransferOptions parallelTransferOptions = new ParallelTransferOptions().setBlockSizeLong(blockSize); this options